# Failed to run dev_appserver.py using Datastore emulator from PyCharm

Tags: python-2.7, pycharm, grpcio

I have a simple `Python 2.7` Google App Engine application.
I set my `PyCharm` Professional IDE to debug or run the app with `Datastore` emulator, and get the following error:

```
`Cannot use the Cloud Datastore Emulator because the packaged grpcio is incompatible to this system. Please install grpcio using pip`
```

I have tried to install this package (`grpcio`) using `pip` with no change

PyCharm runs this command to launch the app:
`/usr/bin/python2.7 /home/netanel/Desktop/google-cloud-sdk/google-cloud-sdk/bin/dev_appserver.py --port 8080 --host localhost --clear_datastore=yes app.yaml --support_datastore_emulator=True`

If I running this command from the terminal window it runs well

Answer (score 5):

Do you have both python 3 and python 2.7 installed? Your `pip install grpcio` is likely installing for python 3 if so. Try

`python2.7 -m pip install grpcio`

to install `grpcio` for your python 2.7 environment that `dev_appserver.py` needs to use to run.